# installing ODS Studio sun path addon in 2.78?

Tags: add-on, customization

I tried to install the ODS Studio engineering tools (specifically sun path, which gives accurate sunlight simuation based on location and date) which worked with Blender 2.63, apparently it doesn't yet work with Blender 2.78. Any way to install? Is there a similar addon in user preferences? TIA

Comment: 2.63 is far back, stuff changed in the meantime it may no longer be compatible with newer versions. How have you installed it, what errors did you get? Neverd heard of this add-on before, where can we get it? Best course of action is probably contact the addon author and ask if it can be updated

Comment: thanks. I use Blender mainly for architecture. When I searched for a tutorial about sun path is blender I came  accross this. In fact, in 2.63 there was an "architecture" category. I recently upgraded my computer so reinstalling everything. The company is ODS Engineering. They do different engineering related simulations. Looks like a great addon, which would be really useful for me so I can do energy studies of a proposed building.

Comment: There is a simple sun addon in [contrib](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC/browse/master/lamp_geographical_sun.py) and while [this one](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Sun_Position) doesn't show the map it otherwise appears to work.